# ListViews become slow when many TableLayouts are in memory

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, android-tablelayout

In the android app that I'm working on lots of data in the form of **tables** (fixed header/column, dynamic content) has to be presented to the user. The user should be able to scroll vertically as well as horizontally to see more data. The tables were implemented using a **custom RelativeLayout** View with **four TableLayouts** for the data.

Table A | Table B

Table C | Table D

The view works great and it is very smooth even when there are 20+ tables are in the memory.

BUT, other parts of the UI (only ListViews as far as I can tell, but I could be wrong) become choppy/slow. The table views are still very smooth. ListViews re-use the views with a Holder pattern and work properly when the Tables are not present.

One thing that I've noticed, is that when I switch the activity from Activity A (where the tables are) -> Activity B, the NavigationDrawer's ListView becomes smooth again, which makes me believe that it **isn't a memory issue**, but a **drawing issue**.

This is how Activity A is structured:

1. GridLayout

   - FrameLayout (with a Fragment inside)

Only a single Fragment is shown at a time. If only a single Fragment is shown at a time, why would having multple of them in the memory effect the performance of ListViews?

I'm at a loss! Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Here's the code that creates the Layouts and Fragments...

```
/**
 * <b>Purpose:</b> Creates a dashlet.
 *
 * @param map
 * @return
 */
private FrameLayout createDashlet(final Map<String, Object> map)
{

    final String guid = SettingsManager.getValueFromMap(
            SettingsManagerKeyEnum.GUID, map
    );
    final Integer viewType = Integer.parseInt((String) SettingsManager
            .getValueFromMap(SettingsManagerKeyEnum.VIEW_TYPE, map, "0")
    );
    final String className = SettingsManager.getValueFromMap(
            SettingsManagerKeyEnum.CLASS_NAME, map
    );

    DashletViewId dashletViewId = DashletViewId.getInstance();
    int index = dashletViewId.getUniqueId(map);

    // Look for to see if the dashlet already exists.
    FrameLayout dashletLayout = (FrameLayout) dashboardGridLayout.findViewById(index);
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

    // Look to see if the dashlet fragment exists in memory.
    DashletFragmentNEW findFragment = (DashletFragmentNEW) manager.findFragmentById(index);
    Boolean shouldAddFragments = false;

    // if there is currently no dashlet layout, create one
    if (dashletLayout == null)
    {
        dashletLayout = createDashletLayout(guid, index, viewType);

        // checks to see if it should immediately add the dashlet fragment
        if (dashboardGridLayout.getChildCount() == 0)
        {
            shouldAddFragments = true;
        }
    }

    if (findFragment == null && className != null)
    {
        DashletFragmentType dashletFragmentType = DashletType.getDashletFragmentType(className);
        switch (dashletFragmentType)
        {
            case TABLE_FIXED_HEADERS:
                findFragment = DashletTableFragmentNEW.newInstance();
                break;
            case LIST:
                findFragment = DashletListFragmentNEW.newInstance();
                break;
            case UNKNOWN:
                Log.e(TAG, "UNKNOWN FRAGMENT");
                break;
        }


        shouldAddFragments = true;
    }

    if (findFragment != null && shouldAddFragments) {
        transaction.add(index, findFragment, guid);
        transaction.commit();

        findFragment.setDashletAllDashletMap(map);
        findFragment.setDashletType(DashletType.fromDashletClassName(className));

        findFragment.setListener(this);
    }

    return dashletLayout;

}
```

There is an Observer that notifies each Fragment whether it should be shown or hidden, which calls:

```
@Override
public void hideFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.hide(fragment);
    ft.commit();
}

@Override
public void showFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.show(fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

**UPDATE 2:** The slowness is not present on the Samsung Note 10.1 (2012), but it is still present on Nexus 5. Note 10.1 has weaker CPU and the same amount of RAM as Nexus 5 (2 GBs)

**UPDATE 3:** Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 GT-P3113 also doesn't show any signs of a slowdown.
**UPDATE 4:** The slow behaviour isn't seen on Moto X either.

Comment: You should post the actual XML layout for your list items as well as the code used to inflate and display your view

Comment: I've added the code that creates the Layouts and Fragments for each layout... Not sure if it is helpful